# Call method from a request in a middleware's terminate method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.2. I have two request classes: `ApiRequests` and `GetUserDetailsRequest`.

`ApiRequests` has a method `shouldLogResponse()` which returns `true`. `GetUserDetailsRequest` extends `ApiRequests` and overrides `shouldLogResponse()` to return `false`.

Also I have a `LoggingMiddleware` class which in his `terminate()` method has the following:

```
$response_content = 'Response is not logged';
if ($request->shouldLogResponse()) {
    $response_content = $response->getContent();
}
ApiLogger::request($request->getPathInfo(), $request->getContent(), $response_content);
```

However it is not working because `$request` is not instance of `GetUserDetailsRequest` class (I presume). How can I get the request class for a specific request in my middleware?

Edit: `GetUserDetailsRequest` is used in the controller.

```
public function getUser(GetUserDetailsRequest $request) { //... }
```

The `LoggingMiddleware` is added to `$middlewareGroups` in my `Http\Kernel.php` in the `api` group. And this `api` group is applied to all of my API routes.

Comment: I think you have to supply more details, as for example where and how did you register and call/inject your classes.

Comment: Is your middleware defined as singleton? Because the terminate method is running a fresh instance...

Comment: @linktoahref It is and is working as expected (there's my validation logic). Simone Cabrino, I'm afraid it's not. How can I do that?

Comment: See answer below...

Answer (score 4):

Your problem was documented in the github issues at the page https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9683 and this brought the moderators to add a descriptive message in the Laravel Documentation.

> When calling the terminate method on your middleware, **Laravel will resolve a fresh instance of the middleware** from the service container. If you would like to use the same middleware instance when the handle and terminate methods are called, register the middleware with the container using the container's singleton method.

Sincerely I never did something like this, but what you need is to register your middleware as a **singleton**. From the [Laravel service container documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/container) I understand that this can be done in a way like this

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('HelpSpot\API', function ($app) {
            return new HelpSpot\API($app->make('HttpClient'));
        });
    }
}
```

But, in order to register a Middleware in a runtime, you have to do something like this

```
$this->app['router']->middleware('middleware_name', App\Middleware\Name::class);
```

Let me know if you understand how to merge together these two methods call.

Comment: After registering my middleware as you showed, how can I apply it to a middleware group? *Edit:* I used named middleware and added to a my route group. However, `exit(get_class($request));` in `terminate()` still says it's `ApiRequests`, not `GetUserDetailsRequest`. :(

Answer (score 0):

I'll follow your clue : `$request`is not instance of `GetUserDetailsRequest`.

In that cas, it would mean that you probably do not inject the right object inside your controller's method.

Try to typehint the correct class to your method, like so :

```
public function index(GetUserDetailsRequest $request)
{}
```

Edit :
Your edit show us that your clue was wrong, if the method is typeHinted, `$request` is an instance of `GetUserDetailsRequest`or it will fail to execute

Comment: If I do `get_class($request)` in my middleware, I get: `App\Http\Requests\ApiRequests`, not: `App\Http\Requests\GetUserDetailsRequest`.

Comment: Oh, my bad, i misunderstood your post, you meant in the middleware.

Comment: So now, are you sure the controller method accessed via this URL is correctly typehinted ?

Comment: I didn't get your question, but everything else works just fine. Except for that terminable middleware and the request class that's used there.

Comment: the middleware will receive an `App\Http\Requests\GetUserDetailsRequest` only if the controller's method is correctly typehinted.

Also, `handle`method of the middleware cant provide depency injection, but you can do so via the middleware constructor

Comment: Can you guide me through this? (how to pass data to the constructor of the middleware)

Comment: simply typehint the `$request` param of the constructor :)

Comment: It's still just `ApiRequests` :(

Comment: I meant you had to use the object from  the constructor so store the `$request` param as an attribute and use it instead of the `$request` of the handle method